# CircleCI 2.0 Workflow - Deploy not working

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I'm trying to set up a workflow in CircleCI for my React project.
What I want to achieve is to get a **job** to build the stuff and another one to deploy the master branch to Firebase hosting.

This is what I have so far after several configurations:

```
witmy: &witmy
  docker:
    - image: circleci/node:7.10

version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    <<: *witmy
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: yarn install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      - run:
          name: Build app in production mode
          command: |
            yarn build

      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: .
  deploy:
    <<: *witmy
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .

      - run:
          name: Deploy Master to Firebase
          command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token=MY_TOKEN

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

The **build job** always success, but with the **deploy** I have this error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail 
./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token=MYTOKEN 

/bin/bash: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase: No such file or directory 
Exited with code 1
```

So, what I understand is that the deploy job is not running in the same place the build was, right?

I'm not sure how to fix that. I've read some examples they provide and tried several things, but it doesn't work. I've also read the documentation but I think it's not very clear how to configure everything... maybe I'm too dumb.

I hope you guys can help me out on this one.

Cheers!!

**EDITED TO ADD MY CURRENT CONFIG USING WORKSPACES**

I've added Workspaces... but still I'm not able to get it working, after a loooot of tries I'm getting this error:

```
Persisting to Workspace 
The specified paths did not match any files in /home/circleci/project
```

And also it's a real pain to commit and push to CircleCI every single change to the config file when I want to test it... :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*disclaimer: I'm a CircleCI Developer Advocate*

Each job is its own running Docker container (or VM). So the problem here is that nothing in `node_modules` exists in your deploy job. There's 2 ways to solve this:

1. Install Firebase and anything else you might need, on the fly, just like you do in the build job.
2. Utilize [CircleCI Workspaces](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#using-workspaces-to-share-data-among-jobs) to carry over your `node_modules` directory from the build job to the deploy job.

In my opinion, option 2 is likely your best bet because it's more efficient.

Comment: Hi Feliciano, thanks for your help and sorry about my late replay. I've edited my question since I've been trying with Workspaces with no luck. Cheers!